# Converting a PDF to text using GhostScript.net, I get an error trying to send the text to the anonymous pipe instead of the writing it to the disk

Tags: c#, pdf, ghostscript, file-conversion, ghostscript.net

I am using Ghostscript to convert PDF files to text via the GhostScript.NET wrapper library.   I was getting it to convert when writing the text to a file  ("-sOutputFile=" + outputPipeHandle), but I'd rather write it to a stream ("-o" + outputPipeHandle).  Here's my attempt in c#:

```
            try
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Installed " + _lastInstalledVersion.LicenseType.ToString() + " Ghostscript " + _lastInstalledVersion.Version.ToString());
                GhostscriptPipedOutput gsPipedOutput = new GhostscriptPipedOutput();
                
                // pipe handle format: %handle%hexvalue
                string outputPipeHandle = "%handle%" + int.Parse(gsPipedOutput.ClientHandle).ToString("X2");

                using (GhostscriptProcessor processor = new GhostscriptProcessor(_lastInstalledVersion, true))
                {
                    processor.Processing += new GhostscriptProcessorProcessingEventHandler(ghostscript_Processing);

                    List<string> switches = new List<string>();
                    switches.Add("-empty");
                    switches.Add("-dQUIET");
                    switches.Add("-dSAFER");
                    switches.Add("-dBATCH");
                    switches.Add("-dNOPAUSE");
                    switches.Add("-dNOPROMPT");
                    if (this.Context.IsPreview)
                    {
                        switches.Add("-dLastPage=5");
                    }
                    switches.Add("-dTextFormat=3");
                    switches.Add("-sDEVICE=txtwrite");
                    switches.Add("-o" + outputPipeHandle);
                    switches.Add("-q");
                    switches.Add("-f");
                    switches.Add(Context.Path);
                        //"-sOutputFile=" + outputPipeHandle

                    try
                    {
                        //processor.Process(switches.ToArray());
                        // THROWS AN ERROR HERE
                        processor.StartProcessing(switches.ToArray(), new ConsoleStdIO(true, true, true));

                        // HERE IS WHERE I HOPE TO GRAB THE TEXT FROM THE PIPED OUTPUT
                        byte[] rawDocumentData = gsPipedOutput.Data;
                        returnVal = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(rawDocumentData);
                        Debug.WriteLine(returnVal);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        returnVal = ex.Message;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        gsPipedOutput.Dispose();
                        gsPipedOutput = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                returnVal = ex.Message;
            }

            return returnVal;
        }
    }
```

my errors are as follows - I'm not so much concerned with the warnings as I am the fatal error about "Could not open the file 958" - as I thought that it would be in memory.

```
   **** Warning: can't process font stream, loading font by the name.
   **** Error reading a content stream. The page may be incomplete.
   **** File did not complete the page properly and may be damaged.
   **** Warning: File has unbalanced q/Q operators (too many q's)
The thread 0x59c0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
   **** Warning: can't process font stream, loading font by the name.
   **** Error reading a content stream. The page may be incomplete.
   **** File did not complete the page properly and may be damaged.
GPL Ghostscript 9.06: **** Could not open the file 958 .
Error: /ioerror in --showpage--
Operand stack:
   1   true
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1926   1   3   %oparray_pop   1925   1   3   %oparray_pop   1909   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   5   1   5   --nostringval--   %for_pos_int_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   1809   0   10   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1173/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:82/200(L)--   --dict:82/200(L)--   --dict:109/127(ro)(G)--   --dict:293/300(ro)(G)--   --dict:25/31(L)--   --dict:6/8(L)--   --dict:21/40(L)--   --dict:7/15(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: Bad file descriptor
GPL Ghostscript 9.06: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
Exception thrown: 'Ghostscript.NET.GhostscriptAPICallException' in Ghostscript.NET.dll
```

#### Update

For additional reference, I'm essentially using this code from the GhostScript.net samples on their website:  [PipedOutputSample.cs](https://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET/blob/master/Ghostscript.NET.Samples/Samples/PipedOutputSample.cs)

The only difference I can see is that I changed the DEVICE to 'txtwrite' instead of 'pdfwrite'.

#### Update 2

After reading the documentation more carefully

> Note that on MS Windows systems, the % character also has a special meaning for the command processor (shell), so you will have to double it.

As I happen to be on Windows, I modified where I name my outputPipeHandle to:
`string outputPipeHandle = "%%handle%%" + int.Parse(gsPipedOutput.ClientHandle).ToString("X2");`

so I no longer get the above error about not being able to access the file.  Instead, my breakpoint on this line is reached

```
byte[] rawDocumentData = gsPipedOutput.Data;
```

but upon trying to copy the value of that Data field to my variable, it completely breaks out of my thread... skipping my catch, and even my finally block.  I don't see any messages as to why it broke out in the output console.  some kind of GhostScript pointer error????

I'm still at a loss.  I don't even know what %handle% is supposed to signify or why I need to use it.   Without that knowledge, I'm operating blind and just throwing stuff hoping it works.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, @Jonathan. About `%handle%` it's Ghostscript native command line stuff, it seems that this exact word is required to handle the file in memory using pipes, but you should get better and deeper explanation from Ghostscipt experts. All I can contribute with is that it worked for our projects in Win7 and Win10 context using simple `%` symbols, not doubled, but if you have solved your first problem using double percentage symbols, maybe it's not the same case as ours.

Comment: On the other hand, I can see some more differences between your code and sample. May I ask why do you use this line `processor.Processing += new GhostscriptProcessorProcessingEventHandler(ghostscript_Processing);` ? We tried the sample and it works ok without it, have you tried removing the line?

Comment: By the way, have you tested you current switches using them as parameters executing from command line and using the Ghostscript native library? This should helps to verify that the parameters are fine and that the sentence should work in a native context.

Comment: Hi Dave, thank you for commenting.   The Processing event handler - It appears I can leave it in or out with no effect.... but with it in I could do stuff like update a progress bar.... it fires once per page as it processes.   currently, I just have a log statement in there writing which page I am processing.   I have also used the same switches as parameters on the command line.   In fact, that's my workaround at the moment, to just run it from the command line with Process.Start().   I don't like that solution as much, but it is working for now, until I track down the issue.

Comment: btw, I am using Ghostscript.NET v1.2.3 64 bit, with GhostScript 9.54.0 installed on my machine.   If your versions are different, please let me know.

Comment: About the ProcessingEventhandler, it's ok. I did not undestand what do you mean with *to just run it from the command line with Process.Start()* as a workaround... Please, could you share the command line invoking sentence you are using? And the exact code for the workaround you mentioned, if possible, and if it differs from the initially posted. We have tested Ghostscript .NET using Ghostscript 9.52, check same code with this version if you want, as it might be helpful.

Comment: I've used same parameters in command line on this sentence `gswin64c.exe -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dTextFormat=3 -sDEVICE=txtwrite -o C:\temp\test.txt -q -f C:\temp\test.pdf `, which executed successfully, creating the txt file as expected.

Comment: When I use the same code you posted, in a C# project with Ghostscript .NET, it does not raise the same error, but a different one indicating *invalidfileaccess*, and *access denied*. If I replace `-dSAFER` parameter with `-dNOSAFER`, the code works, which leads me to guess that there is some problem with Windows accesing the file. Tried to use `--permit-file-write` parameter, without success... Are you able to get to this point?